# C# program passes an uint[] which contains a string pointer to a C++ dll

Tags: c#, string, pointers

I know there is a lot of discussions regarding passing pointer from C# program to a third party C++ dll. But my case is a special one.

I have a third party C++ DLL and I call a function in it by this:

```
[DllImport(@"ThirdParty.DLL", EntryPoint = "?ThirdPartyEntryPoint", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern Int16 ThirdParty_command(uint p1, ushort p2, uint[] data);
```

Now the tricky thing here is that one of the elements in "uint[] data" is a string pointer which points to a string in C++ (type: unsigned char ). I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
String name = "myName";
fixed (char* nameAddress = name)
{
    uint[] data = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02,(uint) nameAddress };
    Int16 result = ThirdParty_command(0, 0, data);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Won't compile? Exception? Please be specific by posting any error messages you receive.

Comment: your mixing `Int16` (internal name) with `uint` (shorthand name). Why? `public static extern short ...`

Comment: Surely this is a struct and not an uint[]?

Comment: It does compile. The ThirdParty.DLL gives error  "Too many parameters"

Comment: Sorry, in my first question the C++ pointer is "char*", NOT "unsigned char"

Comment: I am using VS2010 .NET framwork4. I am pretty sure I don't mix Int16 with uint. I can use "ThirdParty_command" for other purpose without any problem (If "data" doesn't contains a pointer).

Answer (score 0):

Likely caused by the fact that `unsigned char*` is normally `byte[]`, not `uint[]`. Check what type of string is expected on C side, you may need to convert UTF-16 (C# String) to some other encoding like UTF-8.

Comment: Yes, you are right. As I mentioned above, C++ pointer is a "char*"

Comment: I created a small C# and a C++ project to test passing an uint array which contains a pointer pointing to a string. I use "IntPtr ptr = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(myString)" to get the pointer and store it in the array. the C++ side can retrieve the string without any problem. So It could be the third party dll issue